# How to setup bitcoind 10.2 for solo mining on LAN with Bitmain S3

Tags: server, asic

Hy there,
i do not exactly know if i am right with my setup, so please be patient with my questions as a noob.
I have a Bitmain S3 with latest Firmware on the ASIC, and i do not exactly know how to configure the ASIC for solo mining in my LAN.

1.) I have a linux bitcoind server in my lan with the IP 192.168.1.1

2.) I have an ASIC bitmain S3 with the IP 192.168.2.2

3.) I have a bitcoin.conf as follows

```
server=1
daemon=1
listen=1
rpcuser=USER
rpcpassword=SOMEWILDDIGITS
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=192.168.2.2
rpcport=8332
```

4.) What statements do i need in the S3 configuration field? Do i need the **rpcsuser+rpcpwd+btcaaddress** or do i just need the **btcaddress**?

Thanks in advance for your awnsers!!!

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core doesn't directly allow for stratum miners to connect, you need a middleman proxy to translate the two mining methods used by Bitcoin Core and `cgminer` on the Antminer S3. This is simplest with `bfgminer`.

Run [BFGminer](http://bfgminer.org/) on the same computer as Bitcoin Core with the following configuation, it won't need any further settings altered or configured (it gets the RPC password automatically on launch).

```
bfgminer --stratum-port=3333
```

BFGminer will launch, and retrieve the information needed for solo mining.

```
Now using coinbase address 1PkNBPBGEmvoMFbwRT5ky3XXVNstJnJ4c1, provided by pool 0
Network difficulty changed to 49.4G (353.6P)
Pool 0 http://localhost:8332/#getcbaddr#allblocks alive
Long-polling activated for http://localhost:8332/#getcbaddr#allblocks (getblocktemplate)
Added local bitcoin RPC server on port 8332 as pool 0
Probing for an alive pool
Pool 0 http://localhost:8332/#getcbaddr#allblocks alive
```

You're now ready to solo mine against Bitcoin Core, you just have to point your antminer at the IP address of the computer running `BFGminer`, and the miner should show up in the top section of BFGminer with its hashrate showing as "PXY" (stratum proxy). Any blocks will be paid out to the coinbase address shown in `BFGminer`, which is a new one generated from your wallet.

Comment: This simply doesn't work -it makes sense that it would but something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The previous method will work on Windows 10 as well but the missing thing is a stratum proxy.  You must run a proxy for the stratum to connect with the rpc.