# Connecting an Antminer to Bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, solo-mining, antminer

I have this in my bitcoin.conf:

```
rpcallowip=my_ip
rcpport=<port>
rpcuser=<username>
rpcpassword=<password>
```

The problem I am having is my Antminer with Braiins OS says “pool protocol not supported” when I use http://my_ip:port
or “invalid format of pool URL” when I use
my_ip:port

I used https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=417997.0 and [Solo Mine with an AntMiner](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36845/solo-mine-with-an-antminer) to start.

The issue I need solved is getting my Antminer to connect to my Bitcoin Core so I can solo mine using my Bitcoin Core instead of connecting to CKPool or other solo pools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup bitcoind 10.2 for solo mining on LAN with Bitmain S3](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38487/how-to-setup-bitcoind-10-2-for-solo-mining-on-lan-with-bitmain-s3)

Comment: bfgminer will not run at all I found another way on bitcoin talk where you make a stratum proxy on a raspberry pi and point that at your computer and point your miner at the raspberry pi. I will test this method to see if it works.

Comment: if it works, please help other people like you by posting your solution in the "Your Answer" box below.